# POSTFIX: how to determine how many connections are currently active

Tags: postfix

I'm running postfix on a mail server which is used by a couple hundered users.  One user is getting "Connection Interrupted" errors in Outlook when attempting to send.  I have not had reports of this problem from anyone else.

Closing/reopening Outlook does not solve the problem.  Restarting Postfix daemon on my end solves the problem.  It is as if the connections are not being closed cleanly, thus triggering the smtpd_client_connection_count_limit which is set to 8.  Possibly the user's virus scanner is grabbing the SMTP traffic and failing to terminate the session properly...

Is there any way I can see a list of current "open connections" to the postfix service, along with the source IP address and possibly the username used to authenticate?  I want to see if this user's connection count increases over time.

I realise I can use netstat -pt | grep smptd to find open connections to the smtpd daemon and show the remote IP address.  I'm looking for more details which may include username, as there are several users coming into our server from the same IP address as the problem user.

Appreciate any info.

Thanks

Comment: Guess nobody knows the answer...

Comment: our postfix under DDOS attack. Id like to know the answer too

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a list of currently active SMTP connections to Postfix by running lsof on the mail server:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:smtp -i TCP:submission
```

The `lsof` command lists open files, including network connections.  Those two `-i` switches make it show TCP connections to port 25 (SMTP) and port 587 (SMTP Submission port).  If you use different ports, you will need to edit the parameters to the `-i` switches in the example, giving the appropriate service name or port number.

The lsof command should be available on any UNIX-type operating system.  More information about the lsof command can be found here: https://lsof.readthedocs.io/en/stable/